# why I am not getting error when self is being assigned something

Tags: ruby

Based on [this blog](http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/eavesdropping-on-expressions) tap works something like this which I agree with.

```
class Object
  def tap
    yield self
    self
  end
end
```

Here is my experiment

```
class Lab
end

puts Lab.new.tap {|e| e = 'Boom' }
```

In the above case since I am attempting to change the value of self then ruby should blow up. But it does not blow up.

Given below is a case where an attempt to change self blows up. So my question is why ruby is not blowing up in the above case.

```
class Lab
  def lab
    puts self
    self = 'Boom' #=> exception Can't change the value of self
    puts self
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the same as the reason why `self` isn't assigned to in this code snipplet:

```
hello = self
hello = 'foo'
```

`e` is just a variable, assigning something else to it just assigns something else to it, it doesn't affect *the current value* of e.

Comment: is e a clone of self? Since ruby uses pass by reference then I would think that changing e would change self.

Comment: `e` is a variable that contains a reference to self. When assigning something else to `e` the variable contains a reference something else. The important thing here is that `e` _is a variable_, variables are references to objects, _they are not the objects_. `self` is a special variable that Ruby won't let you assign to, think of it as a constant (but remember that a variable can contain a reference to the same object that a constant is a reference to, so `e` can be a reference to the same object as `self`, but that doesn't mean that any of them are actually the _object_ that they reference).

Answer (score 2):

But you aren't assigning `self`, you are assigning a local variable `e`. When the block opens, `e` refers to the object `self` passed in. Then `e` is reassigned to refer to a String instance.