# Why are none of my node children getting set?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code, and was wondering if someone can tell me why, after running it, the value of `@left_child` and `@right_child` are still nil.

I think I know why, but I am asking for confirmation to the community. Also, is there a way I can make this work in a way like this?

```
 module BinaryTree
    class Node
        attr_accessor :left_child, :right_child

        def initialize(value)
            @value = value
            @left_child = nil
            @right_child = nil
        end

        def add_child(value)
            if value > @value
                create_child(value, @right_child)
            else
                create_child(value, @left_child)
            end
        end

        private

        def create_child(value, which_child)
            if which_child.nil?
                which_child = Node.new(value)
            else
                which_child.add_child(value)
            end
        end
    end
end

node = BinaryTree::Node.new(50)

node.add_child(20)
node.left_child # => nil

node.add_child(70)
node.right_child # => nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are still nil because you've never assign values to them. Instead, you should change to this:

```
module BinaryTree
  class Node
    attr_accessor :left_child, :right_child

    def initialize(value)
      @value = value
      @left_child = nil
      @right_child = nil
    end

    def add_child(value)
      if value > @value
        @right_child = create_child(value, @right_child)
      else
        @left_child = create_child(value, @left_child)
      end
    end

    private

    def create_child(value, which_child)
      if which_child.nil?
        which_child = Node.new(value)
      else
        which_child.add_child(value)
      end
      which_child
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`which_child` is a variable local to `create_child`. The value of `@right_child` is being *copied* to it when you call the method. Your code is basically the same as

```
right_child = nil
which_child = right_child
which_child = true
# right_child is still nil!
```

Variables in Ruby store pointers to objects, and Ruby passes around those pointers by *value*. See also:

- [Ruby - Parameters by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949)
- [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)