# Rails controller: Applying filter to ActiveRecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a bunch of objects getting prepared for a query in my controller. I pass these objects off to a method to be filtered since the same filter is applied in multiple actions in the same controller.

```
def some_action
    foos = Foo.where(nil)
    filter_foos(foos)

    stuff
end

def some_other_action
    foos = Foo.where(nil)
    filter_foos(foos)

    other_stuff
end

def filter_objects(objects)
    objects = objects.where(:bar => "baz")
end
```

Calling filter_objects, however, doesn't seem to change foos. Moreover, it doesn't even show up in my query when I launch a controller request to some_action. Putting `raise objects.length.inspect` on either side of the `objects = objects.where` in my filter method shows that the length of `objects` remains unchanged.

I think I've got some sort of fundamental misunderstanding of how objects or queries work in Ruby/Rails. Could someone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the objects passed into filter_objects and have that affects foos in the outer scope. I get confused about this myself. You might want to read about [Ruby parameter handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949).

Instead, do:

```
foos = filter_objects(foos)
```

And change the definition to:

```
def filter_objects(objects)
    objects.where(:bar => "baz")
end
```

Comment: This was the next option, to set the objects equal to the return value of the method. It works, too; this is what I get for being lazy :)