# Local variables when calling methods and method invocation variables

Tags: ruby

In the following code, `a` is initialized outside of `times`, but `times` creates an inner scope, and `a` is accessible:

```
a = 5
3.times do |n|
  a = 3
end
a # => 3
```

The return value of `a` is `3` because `a` is available from the scope created by `3.times do ... end`, which allows re-assigning the value of `a`. In fact, it re-assigned `a` to `3` three times.

Why is the following different from above?

```
a = 5
def adder(num)
  num = 3
end
adder(a) # => 3
a # => 5
```

It is because we bring in `a`, but it does not change the local variable, maybe because its a method. I don't know. Why is `a` `5` and not `3`?

Comment: Why is your method called `adder`? It doesn't add anything.

Comment: yea sorry I just was trying to figure out scoping rules.  Disregard the dumb method name,  I thought I understood scoping rules in ruby but I am confusing myself I think.  The rules aren't clear to me.  

does a=3 in the first example because there is scope leak in blocks?  Or is it because of the a=3 reassignment? 

Then in the 2nd example does a = > 5 at the end because variables are passed into methods by value not by reference?  what if there was a << operation inside the method would that affect the value of a?  Its so confusing

Comment: You can modify (mutate) a passed object via its methods, e.g. `array << element`. But you can't reassign the outer scope's variable from within a method. Trying to do so will just create a local variable in the method's inner scope. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 2):

All Ruby variables without a glyph (`@`, `@@`, `$`) are local to the current method, module, class, or current program.

```
a = 5  # local to program

def adder
  # local to method
  num = 3
  puts num
end
adder(1)
# => 3

module Foo
  # local to module
  num = 2
  puts num
end
# => 2

class Bar
  # local to class
  num = 1
  puts num
end
# => 1

a      # local to program
# => 5
```

Within those, variables are scoped to the block where they are introduced, as you note yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are not the same. First one is a method **invocation** with a block. Blocks are *closures*, meaning they remember context in which they are defined in (retaining references to variables in that scope, in particular).

The second one is a method **definition**. It is not a closure. In fact, it's a so-called "scope gate". Which means when definition of a method(/class/module) starts, all previously known local variables are pushed out of scope. So, if you were to access `a` from inside `adder`, you'd get a `NameError`.

And also, as @Atri noted, your method definition has no chances to work as you expect. You don't even assign to `a` there. So how do you expect `a` to change?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is `a` 5 and not 3?
>
> ```
> a = 5
> def adder(num)
>   num = 3
> end
> adder(a) # => 3
> a # => 5
> ```

Because when you call `adder` with `a`, it is [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949). So when the value of `num` changes, it doesn't change the value of `a`.

if you want `a` to change value, you need to do `a = adder(a)`.

Comment: ok that makes sense, so lets say this method was given an array as a parameter, and we modify that array using << inside the method.  Then this would mutate that variable correct?  So if I asked for that array again later, its values would have changed since now we mutated the array.  it is being passed by reference not value.   Is that right?

Comment: "Then this would mutate that variable correct?" – No, it would mutate the *array* that the variable *points to*. It would *not* mutate the variable. "So if I asked for that array again later, its values would have changed since now we mutated the array." – Yes, exactly. Because you mutated the *array*, and *not* because you mutated the variable. You cannot mutate a variable with a method call (`<<` is just a method call), *only* with an assignment. …

Comment: … "it is being passed by reference not value." – No. Everything is always passed by value in Ruby. When you mutate the array using `<<`, you are mutating the array. You are *not* changing the variable. The variable still points to the exact same object as it did before. It's just that the object has a different internal state. That has nothing to do with pass-by-reference. That's just mutable state. Ruby is not a purely functional language, you *can* mutate the state of objects.