# Changing the object identity of a formal parameter

Tags: ruby

I will try to explain the problem with a simple example:

```
def enclose(x)
  [x]
end
```

In my application, `enclose` does something more complex, but in essence it returns an array, the content of which is solely determined by the value of the parameter x. I could it use it like this:

```
foo = 'abcd'
....
foo = enclose(foo)
```

Now to my question: Is it possible to write a method `enclose!`, which simply replaces the parameter by its enclosed version, so that the example could be written as

```
foo = 'abcd'
....
enclose!(foo)
```

Since Ruby passes arguments by reference, I thought hat this could maybe be possible. The naive approach,

```
def enclose!(x)
    x = [x]
end
```

does not work - I think this is because the assignment creates a new object and leaves the actual parameter untouched.

Is there way, that I can achieve my goal? I think in Smallalk, there would be a method `become` which would change the object identity, but I didn't find something similar in Ruby.

Comment: Isn't `foo = enclose(foo)` what you really want?

Comment: It's the same (as you can see from my posting), just that I wanted to mention the variable `foo` once. I took the idea from the String methods `chomp` of `chomp!`, but with a `String`, it works, because you can change the content of the string without changing the identity of the String object. In my case, a value of some arbitrary type would have been changed to a value of type `Array`, and I now realize that this is not possible in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some other interesting posts about how [ruby is pass by value, but the values are references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949).

What it boils down to is, you can modify the variable an object refers to, but you cannot change it to refer to another object.

```
> a = [1]
=> [1]
> def add_a(array)
>   array << "a"
> end
=> :add_a
> add_a a
=> [1, "a"]
> a
=> [1, "a"]
```

Answer (score 3):

> Since Ruby passes arguments by reference, I thought hat this could maybe be possible.

Ruby is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference, which you have proven yourself, because otherwise your code would have worked.

> I think in Smallalk, there would be a method become which would change the object identity, but I didn't find something similar in Ruby.

There isn't. Ruby has neither pass-by-reference nor `become:`, what you want simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to sort of accomplish what you are asking for but it's not quite pretty. Ruby has this concept of a binding (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html), which is like a `CallContext` in .NET.

You can do something like this:

```
def enclose(x)
  [x]
end

def enclose!(x, binding)
  eval("#{x} = [#{x}]", binding)
end

foo = 'abcd'
enclose!(:foo, binding)
=> ["abcd"]
```

In the script above, the `:foo` means you are passing the name of the variable, and the `binding` (context) where to find its value. Then you're dynamically calling `eval` to evaluate the assignment operation `foo = [foo]`.