# In Rails, why are my controller params being modified by the class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller action somewhat similar to this:

```
def reports
  puts params
  @stats = Client.stats(params)
  puts params
end
```

The initial params might look like this:

```
{ end: '2012-01-01 21:00:19' }
```

And in my Client model, I have this:

```
def self.stats(opts)
  opts[:start] = (Time.now - 30.days).to_i
  ...do some calculations..
  return stats
end
```

If I inspect the params object that was sent before and after the function runs, I can see it's been modified by the self.stats method.

In the example above, I'm not sending 'start' in the initial params, the method adds it for the calculations - as expected.

What I was not expecting was that the function would modify the original hash!

Can someone explain why this is happening?

--EDIT--

I forgot to say I tried to create a copy of the params and use that instead, same issue.

```
def reports
  a = params
  @stats = Client.stats(a)
  puts params
end
```

The params are still updated?!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949

Comment: Just adding that it is probably a good practice to never alter parameters to a method. It will confuse the caller of that method.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it modify what you're passing in? Creating a new reference to the same object doesn't create a new object, it creates a new reference. Perhaps you want to clone or deep-clone the object?

Comment: Because we have to normalise the date into a standard format which we then modify in a number of queries across different databases - mysql, mongo, a redis query, elasticsearch and big query. It's easier for us to start with a standard time and modify as we go depending on the query we're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's, because your function call gets a reference to the params not a copy. If you do something like `opts[:start] = (Time.now - 30.days).to_i` you are editing the params object.

`a = params`: now both variables point to the same place in the memory. You copied the pointer only.

Google for `ruby object copy` or `ruby deep copy` or search at stackoverflow for it. At a first try you could try `params.clone`.

Comment: I tried to make a copy, see edit, and that's updated too. How can I made a copy of the object then??

Comment: No, you didn't. `params` and `a` points to the same place in the memory. You copied the pointer only. Google for `ruby object copy` or `ruby deep copy` or search at stackoverflow for it. At a first try you could try `params.clone`.

Comment: I was unaware of this! Great, can you add to your answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are updating any value of params, take a copy of params like this

> **a = params.clone**

It will create a new element in memory

if you do like this it wont create a new element in memory it will point the same memory

> **a = params**

Try this