# Ruby n.times issue

Tags: ruby

In use Ruby 2.3, irb

```
a, b = [], [1,2,3]
3.times do
  b[0] += 1
  a << b
end
```

expected:

```
=> [[2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

but I get

```
=> [[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

**why? Thanks**

P.S.

if I do

```
a = []
3.times do |n|
  a << n
end
```

I get right result `a == [0,1,2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the same because `b` is the same object which you are appending 3 times in `a`. `b` remains unchanged. That's why `a` stores the same values.

```
p a.map(&:object_id) # => three same object id referencing to b.
```

Even if you do `a[0][1] = 100`, you will see the same value reflected in all positions `=> [[4, 100, 3], [4, 100, 3], [4, 100, 3]]`

You should use [`Array#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) to save intermediate `b` values.

```
a, b = [], [1,2,3]
3.times do
  b[0] += 1
  a << b.dup
end
=> [[2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

For latter part of you question you might want to read - [Ruby - Parameters by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949)

Comment: Added link to explain latter part of the question. `n` is the different reference each time in that block. :)