# Array assign vs. append behavior

Tags: ruby

The following behavior looks to me like the `assign` method is processing `visited` by value, whereas the `append` method is treating it as a reference:

```
class MyClass
  def assign(visited)
    visited += ["A"]
  end
  def append(visited)
    visited << "A"
  end
end

instance = MyClass.new
visited = []

instance.assign(visited)
visited # => []

instance.append(visited)
visited # => ["A"]
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

This is not a question about whether Ruby supports pass by reference or pass by value, but rather about the example provided below, and why two methods that purportedly do the same thing exhibit different behaviors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - Parameters by reference or by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value)

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll I don't think that question is related. This example (apparently) exhibits both pass-by-reference and pass-by-value behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redefine local variable in the first method.

This is the same as

```
visited = []
local_visited = visited
local_visited = ['A']
visited
# => []
```

And in the second method:

```
visited = []
local_visited = visited
local_visited << 'A'
visited
# => ["A"]
```

Comment: Coupled with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value), it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of `MyClass#assign` which mutates `visited`:

```
class MyClass
  def assign(visited = [])
    visited[0] = "A"
  end
  def append(visited = [])
    visited << "A"
  end
end

instance = MyClass.new
visited = []

instance.assign(visited)
p visited # => ["A"]

visited = []
instance.append(visited)
p visited # => ["A"]
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't get why `visited[0] = "A"` mutates but not `visited += ["A"]`?

Comment: @FloatingRock `visited += ['A']` is actually `visited = visited + ['A']`, so it defines a new object. `visited[0] = 'A'` keeps the same object, but modifies its first element.

Comment: Ah, hence the difference between `<<` and `+=`. The `<<` works because it makes changes in place.