# Ruby instance variable and hash key - how it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please someone tell me how it works? Setting of hash key with the same name with instance variable @remote take affect on its own value... How?

```
@remote = { url: '/user/validate', type: :post }
@config = {}
@config[:remote] = {}

def test
  @config[:remote] = @remote

  data = { data: 'some data' }
  @config[:remote][:data] = data
end

# call method test
test

p @remote.to_s # => "{:url=>\"/user/validate\", :type=>:post, :data=>{:data=>\"some data\"}}"
p @config.to_s # => "{:remote=>{:url=>\"/user/validate\", :type=>:post, :data=>{:data=>\"some data\"}}}"
```

Comment: You're wondering why `@remote` gets a `:data` key when you say `@config[:remote][:data] = data`?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short yes, exactly ...

Comment: `@config[:remote] = @remote` doesn't copy `@remote`, it just assigns a reference. Look at `@config[:remote].object_id` and `@remote.object_id`. All values in Ruby are references (but not all of them are mutable so implementations can take short cuts with things like `11` and `true`) so assignment just copies the reference not what it refers to. There are probably hundreds of duplicates of this, it is a very common point of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is one of many languages that distinguish "immediate values" and "reference values".

If I say `x = 5; y = x; y = 6`, then `x` is an immediate value, and still contains `5`, not `6`.

But if I say `x = { value: 5 }`, then `x` is a reference to a hash object. When I say `y = x` then `y` refers to the same hash object as `x` does. So `y[:value] = 6` will make `x[:value] == 6`.

To prevent this behavior, look up "ruby deep copy", and use `y = x.dup`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value

Comment: But if you `x = 5; y = x` then both `x` and `y` refer to the same object, the `y = 6` part is a bit misleading. The difference between the two examples is that `5` is immutable but a hash is not. AFAIK the immediacy of immutable objects like `11`, `:symbol`, ... is an implementation detail in MRI rather than a property of Ruby itself. And `#dup` doesn't do a deep copy as `h1 = { k: [11] }; h2 = h1.dup; h2[:k].push(23)` will show.