# Next key/value pair overwrites the existing pair in a hash while trying to add pair with new key

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have:

```
fruits = {
  "orange" => {:season => "winter"},
  "apple" => {:season => "winter"},
  "banana" => {:season => "summer"},
  "grape" => {:season => "spring"},
  "peach" => {:season => "winter"},
  "pineapple" => {:season => "summer"}
}
```

I want to get:

```
{
  "winter"=>["orange", "apple", "peach"],
  "summer"=>["banana", "pineapple"],
  "spring"=>["grape"]
}
```

I did:

```
def sort_fruits(fruits_hash)
  fruits=[]
  sorted = {}
  seasons = fruits_hash.map {|k, v|v[:season]}
  seasons.uniq.each do |season|
    fruits.clear
    fruits_hash.each do |fruit, season_name|
      if season == season_name[:season]
        fruits << fruit
      end
    end
    p sorted[season] = fruits ## season changes to new season, so this should have created new key/value pair for new season.
  end
  sorted
end
```

I get:

```
{
  "winter"=>["grape"],
  "summer"=>["grape"],
  "spring"=>["grape"]
}
```

I couldn't figure out why adding new key/value pair with unique key would overwrite existing pair in a hash. Any help with explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you've already received your answer,  your method can also be rewritten to: `fruits.group_by { |k,v| v[:season] }.transform_values {|v| v.map(&:first) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby mutable objects are passed by reference. It means that when you iterate over `seasons` in `each` block this line:

```
sorted[season] = fruits
```

saves to `sorted[season]` a reference to `fruits`, for every season. After `each` loop finishes every season has a reference to the same `fruits` array, which contain items calculated on the last step of the iterator. In your case, it's `["grape"]`.

Comment: Thanks llya for the explanation!

Comment: See [this](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%7B%20num%3A%201%20%7D%0Ab%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A3.times%20do%0A%20%20b.push%28a%29%0A%20%20a%5B%3Anum%5D%20%2B%3D%201%0Aend%0Aputs%20b&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=ruby&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) for a vivid demo (click Visualize Execution, then keep clicking Forward to progress).

Comment: Technically speaking ruby is strictly pass by value.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827566/ruby-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value/22827949#22827949

Comment: ```It's pass-by-value, but all the values are references```. So it's more a question of terminology that can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you reuse the same `fruits` array for all the values. Even though you clear it, is is still the same array. If instead of `fruits.clear` you use `fruits = []` then you won't have the issue.

You can see the issue in the following as an example:

```
arr = ['val']
hash = {
  key1: arr,
  key2: arr
}
p hash # => { key1: ['val'], key2: ['val'] }

arr.clear
p hash # => { key1: [], key2: [] }
```

You could alternatively use `sorted[season] = fruits.clone` or `sorted[season] = [*fruits]` ... anything that uses a new array.

You have to keep track of when you use 'mutation' methods (those that change objects in-place such as `clear`) - this is a common pitfall when working with hashes and arrays

Comment: Thanks max. The explanation and demonstration was really helpful for the beginners like me.