# Ruby passing arguments: difference between Array and Set

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to put an array to another existing array and moreover to put all its items to an existing set. Here's the minimal example:

```
require "set"

def add(myarr, bigarr, myset)
    bigarr << myarr
    myset |= Set.new(myarr)
end

bigarr = []
myset = Set.new

add([1, 2], bigarr, myset)
```

Which yields `bigarr = [1, 2]` .. OK, but `myset = {}` .. is empty. I know little about passing arguments in Ruby (should be by-value) -- in case of array the value should be a reference to its content, then I have no clue what could be the value of set.

The questions are:

1. What is the substantial difference between `Array` and `Set` which causes this behavior?
2. Is there any way to force Ruby pass-by-reference or is there a different recommended way how to solve the problem with referencing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the difference between arrays and sets. You're modifying the array with the `<<` method, but you're reassigning the `myset` variable with the `|=` operator. You never modify the set you passed in. What you want is probably `myset.merge(myarr)`.

Comment: Great answer, I just think OP aimed to use `||=`, `|=` is bit operator and makes no sense in this context.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: It's bitwise-or for Fixnums and Bignums, but Set and Array use it as the set union operator. I think the operator was semantically right, but the problem is just that OP wanted a destructive operation and `|` isn't one.

Comment: can you point me to the docs for that? Don't see it neither in Set/Array nor Enumerable.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel [`Set#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-7C)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: Yeah, Ruby desugars any operator followed by `=` that way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here actually comes from this particular line:

```
 myset |= Set.new(myarr)
```

Here you're creating new object on old variable name. You're replacing one pointer with another, however this only modifies local copy of it. Original object will still exists in memory and outside function, pointer will point to old object (empty set) (tbh: I would not really encourage this kind of writing in ruby with side effects).

If you change it to

```
require "set"

def add(myarr, bigarr, myset)
    bigarr << myarr
    myset.add(myarr)
end

bigarr = []
myset = Set.new

add([1, 2], bigarr, myset)
```

It's working properly - because you modify existing object and don't create new one.

There is great answer that goes more thoroughly into this, right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16464640/1975116

Comment: Based on the `myset |= Set.new(myarr)`, it seems like OP wanted to union the contents of myarr into the set rather than add the array itself.

Comment: Exactly, @Chuck's answer does what it is supposed to do. #merge method modifies existing instance, |= creates new one. Thanks, I understand now.