# Ruby assignment behavior

Tags: ruby

please help find some article of the next behavior.

```
a = 'qwer'
a = b
b << 'ty'
puts b # => 'qwerty'
puts a # => 'qwerty'
```

but if

```
a = 'qwer'
a = b
b = 'ty'
puts b # => 'ty'
puts a # => 'qwer'
```

I know why in this case

I know that it works well, but I can not find an explanation - why so

P.S.

if applicable - please give the links to the articles on this subject (or similar Maybe i miss more interesting feature like this).

Thn.

Comment: [This answer][1] could be what you are looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value/10974116#10974116

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
a = b
```

you make variable `a` keep reference to the same object as variable `b`. That's why when you type:

```
b << 'ty'
```

string contained in variable `a` will also change - this is the same `String` instance.

On the other hand, let's say you have variable `b` containing reference to string `'qwer'`. 
If you have:

```
a = b
b = 'ty'
```

in first line you assign variable `a` to the same object as `b`. In the second line, you assign a new `String` object to variable `b`. So in the end both variables have references to different objects.