# Multivariable Assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why if I add a property to foo, somehow bar also inherits that property when I do this:

```
var foo = bar = {};
foo.hi = 'hi';

console.log(bar); //Object {hi: "hi"}
```

How does this work? I'm setting properties on foo, not bar. I realized I passed the object to bar and then bar to foo, but I must be missing something here.

Integer assignment works differently and more sense (to me anyhow):

```
var foo = bar = 5;
foo = 4;

console.log(bar); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. Strings and number literals are not. In your code `foo === bar`, is the same object. You can simply declare the variables separately:

```
// Two different object instances
var foo = {};
var baz = {};
```

Comment: This appears to be the same with PHP. Is this common? What other langs do this if you know?

Comment: PHP is the same with Std Classes AFAIK.

Comment: @doremi PHP has made its behavior more consistent in this regard in recent versions. php 4, for instance a lot more times an object was passed as a copy vs a reference, necessitating use of the & modifier to force pass by reference. Anyway, to answer your question Python works similarly to JS in this way. Also, ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value

Answer (score 1):

by doing `foo = bar = {};`, foo and bar are pointers to same object. so when you do:

```
foo.hi = 'hi';
```

It sets `bar.hi` also, because `foo` and `bar` point to the same object. To make it different, you should do:

```
var foo = {},  bar = {};
foo.hi = 'hi';
```