# Two-dimensional array, how to create column array that modifies original array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array, and I want to be able to use another array which refers to the column of the original one. I can do it with rows, but I can't figure out how to do it with columns.

```
twodim = [[" "," "," "], [" "," "," "], [" "," "," "]]
row1 = twodim[0]
row1[0] = "X"

col1 = << twodim[0][0] << twodim[1][0] << twodim[2][0]
col1[2] = "X"

=> puts twodim
#actual result
=> [["X", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]
#desired result
=> [["X", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], ["X", " ", " "]]
```

I've tried using map! but that ends up causing the original twodim array to change when I just try to assign the columns to variables. I've also tried transpose but that returns a new array. Is there a way to create an array using the object id's from the original array in order to be able to modify it? This is for a tictactoe program, and I'm writing the ai for it. I'm trying to check if there's a way to win the game in a given row or column, then have it fill in the winning spot if it exists. Here's the rest of it if it helps:

```
    rows = [row1, row2, row3]
    cols = [col1, col2, col3]
    rows.map do |row|
        if !row.include?(@player) && row.count(@ai) == 2 then
            row.fill(@ai)
            return
        end
    end
    cols.each do |col|
        if !col.include?(@player) && col.count(@ai) == 2 then
            col.fill(@ai)
            puts "col = #{col}"
            return
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-replace)

```
twodim = [[" "," "," "], [" "," "," "], [" "," "," "]]
row1 = twodim[0]
row1[0] = "X"
col1 = [twodim[0][0], twodim[1][0], twodim[2][0]]

col1[2].replace("X")

twodim
# => [["X", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], ["X", " ", " "]]
```

Explanation:

In your example, when doing `col1[2] = "X"` you are assigning to the object `col1[2]` a new variable with the value `"X"`, that means that `col1[2]` is now storing the reference of the new object `"X"`. However, when doing `col1[2].replace("X")` the method `replace` is changing the content of the object that is referenced by col1[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value).

The following example will clarify the above explanation:

```
$> col1[1].object_id
# => 2161281980 
$> col1[1] = "X"
# => "X" 
$> col1[1].object_id # Different object_id !!!
# => 2161469100
$> col1[1].replace("X")
# => "X" 
$> col1[1].object_id
# => 2161469100 # Same object_id !!!
```

I also recommend you to read this post: *[Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)*