# What does pass by value mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm clearly not quite understanding pass by value properly.

```
irb(main):001:0> a="UPPER CASE STRING"
=> "UPPER CASE STRING"
irb(main):002:0> b=a
=> "UPPER CASE STRING"
irb(main):003:0> a
=> "UPPER CASE STRING"
irb(main):004:0> b
=> "UPPER CASE STRING"
irb(main):005:0> b.downcase
=> "upper case string"
irb(main):006:0> a
=> "UPPER CASE STRING"
irb(main):007:0> b.downcase!
=> "upper case string"
irb(main):008:0> b
=> "upper case string"
irb(main):009:0> a
=> "upper case string"
irb(main):010:0>
```

Why is a lowercase, if pass by value then isn't b a copy of a ?

Is this because a is a (reference|pointer) to a String object and therefore b is a copy of the pointer not the object ?

Comment: You are not passing any arguments here, pass-by-value doesn't even come into play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every object in Ruby has its own *id*. You can see the same using `#object_id`. Follow code :

```
a = "UPPER CASE STRING"
b = a
a.object_id # => 70041560
b.object_id # => 70041560
```

`b` and `a` pointing to the same object. `b.downcase` [returns a copy of receiver with all uppercase letters replaced with their lowercase counterparts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase), not *downcased* the original string object. That's the reason after `b.downcase`, you didn't see the same change in `a`, while you were inspecting `a` in *irb*. But if you also inpect `b`, after `b.downcase`, you would also see the output of `b` as `"UPPER CASE STRING"`.

```
b.downcase.object_id # => 78657980
```

But `b.downcase!` [changed the original *string* object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21). As you modified the original receiver *string* object, thus `b` and `a` both now will output as `"upper case string"`.

```
b.downcase!.object_id # => 70041560
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this because a is a (reference|pointer) to a String object and
>   therefore b is a copy of the pointer not the object ?

Yes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value, 2nd answer seems to explain this quite well. I'm going to close this.