# Can I send an intact variable to another module?

Tags: ruby

Just wondering if something like this is possible:

```
module A
    def sender
        varA = 'foobz'
        B.public_send('receiver', varA)
    end
end
module B
    def receiver
        puts varA #=> 'foobz'
    end
end
```

Here I'm trying to send **varA**, which is defined in **module A**, to **module B**, intact. By intact I mean we're not putting it in a hash or anything, we make **varA** pop into existence in **B.receiver**.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: if by "pop into existence" you mean [pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value) then yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this:

```
module A
  def self.sender
    varA = 'foobz'
    B.public_send('receiver', varA)
  end
end

module B
  def self.receiver(varA)
    puts varA #=> 'foobz'
  end
end

A.sender #=> foobz
```

You have defined instance methods, but modules don't have instances.  Also, you need to pass `varA` as an argument.

Or perhaps this is what you have in mind:

```
module A
  def self.sender
    B.instance_variable_set(:@varA, 'foobz')
    B.public_send('receiver') 
  end
end

module B
  def self.receiver
    puts @varA #=> 'foobz'
  end
end

A.sender #=> foobz
```