# Calling super without arguments

Tags: ruby

According to the [documentation for modules and classes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance), calling `super` (without arguments or parentheses) calls the parent method with the same arguments:

> When used without any arguments `super` uses the arguments given to the subclass method.

Assigning a new value to the "argument variable" seems to alter this behavior:

```
class MyClass
  def foo(arg)
    puts "MyClass#foo(#{arg.inspect})"
  end
end

class MySubclass < MyClass
  def foo(arg)
    puts "MySubclass#foo(#{arg.inspect})"
    super
    arg = 'new value'
    super
  end
end

MySubclass.new.foo('inital value')
```

Output:

```
MySubclass#foo("inital value")
MyClass#foo("inital value")
MyClass#foo("new value")       # <- not the argument given to MySubclass#foo
```

Is this expected?

#### Update

This [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981577/477037) the expected behavior for positional and keyword arguments, but it doesn't work for block arguments:

```
class MyClass
  def foo(&block)
    puts "MyClass#foo { #{block.call.inspect} }"
  end
end

class MySubclass < MyClass
  def foo(&block)
    puts "MySubclass#foo { #{block.call.inspect} }"
    super
    block = Proc.new { 'new value' }
    super
  end
end

MySubclass.new.foo { 'initial value' }
```

Output:

```
MySubclass#foo { "initial value" }
MyClass#foo { "initial value" }
MyClass#foo { "initial value" }
```

Comment: But.. you changed the value of the variable `arg`,,, that's why result got changed. Nothing _magic_ :) Documentation not looks like _wrong_.

Comment: Read [keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) doco. It is more clear.

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert, but it sounds logic to me. You did change the argument value so what is passed to parent method is the pointer to the variable which itself has no change but has a new content. (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: It looks strange to me. `arg` before assignment is one local variable, and the assigned `arg` is another local variable with the same name. Unless calling the super method is done through explicit reference to the variable names, it does not make sense.

Comment: @ArupRakshit sure, I assign a new value to a local variable. But isn't `super` supposed to call the method using the same arguments?

Comment: I am curious what happens if you receive the arguments without explicit names, like `def foo(_)` or `def foo(*)`.

Comment: @sawa you can assign to `_` which results in the same behavior. `*` on the other hand doesn't create any local variables.

Comment: @Stefan Right. So it looks like the easy to think about it, which confirms to what Arup wrote, is that argument-less `super` is not evaluated  separately, but is simply replaced by the exact expression as the method was called, and then the whole method is evaluated. I feel this is similar to how `include`-ing a module works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets take one example from the Ruby core:

[`Keyword2`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e84e56db54d15ff01558a1cc47952c3bead381df/test/ruby/test_super.rb#L56-L64)

```
class Base
  def single(a) a end
  def double(a, b) [a,b] end
  def array(*a) a end
  def optional(a = 0) a end
  def keyword(**a) a end
end

class Keyword2 < Base
  def keyword(foo: "keyword2")
    foo = "changed1"
    x = super
    foo = "changed2"
    y = super
    [x, y]
  end
end
```

Now, see the [test case](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e84e56db54d15ff01558a1cc47952c3bead381df/test/ruby/test_super.rb#L132-L134) :-

```
def test_keyword2
  assert_equal([{foo: "changed1"}, {foo: "changed2"}], Keyword2.new.keyword)
end
```

Above example exactly mathes the [keyword documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/).

> ***Called with no arguments and no empty argument list, super calls the appropriate method with the same arguments, and the same code block, as those used to call the current method***. Called with an argument list or arguments, it calls the appropriate methods with exactly the specified arguments (including none, in the case of an empty argument list indicated by empty parentheses).

**same arguments** means it is saying the *current values of argument variables*.[`test_super.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e84e56db54d15ff01558a1cc47952c3bead381df/test/ruby/test_super.rb) files contains all the varieties of stuffs we can do with `super` in Ruby.

No, it work with block too (taken from [core](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e84e56db54d15ff01558a1cc47952c3bead381df/test/ruby/test_super.rb#L511-L527)) :

```
a = Class.new do
  def foo
    yield
  end
end

b = Class.new(a) do
  def foo
    super{
      "b"
    }
  end
end

b.new.foo{"c"} # => "b"
```

But, have no idea why the below is giving `"c"`? This is actually the updated question of the OP:

```
c = Class.new do
  def foo(&block)
    block.call
  end
end

d = Class.new(c) do
  def foo(&block)
     block = -> { "b" }
    super
  end
end

d.new.foo{"c"} # => "c"
```

Comment: So it looks like `super` without arguments is not evaluating on its own what method and arguments to evaluate, but `super` is simply replaced with literally the same expression as it was called.

Comment: If you don't want that behaviour just call `super()` that'll call without arguments.

Comment: @Sigurd Humm.. The OP thought, values of argument variable Ruby cached, but Ruby doesn't. What it cached is the variable names, not their initial values.

Comment: This is more about variable scope I guess. I did not expect `super` to evaluate the local variables every time it is called.

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't work for block arguments! (see update above)

Comment: @Stefan See the update.. But I don't know. How your example differs from the one from core. Need to check.

Comment: @ArupRakshit in your example, `super` is called with an explicit argument.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be the expected behavior, based on the [`RubySpec`](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/tree/archive) anyway.

```
module RestArgsWithSuper
  class A
    def a(*args)
      args
    end
  end

  class B < A
    def a(*args)
      args << "foo"

      super
    end
  end
end
```

([`language/fixtures/super.rb`](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/91ce9f65493a18acc401dc7ded0e79e0226a03c6/language/fixtures/super.rb#L293)).

It's then expected that the arguments are modified:

```
it "passes along modified rest args when they weren't originally empty" do
  Super::RestArgsWithSuper::B.new.a("bar").should == ["bar", "foo"]
end
```

([`language/super_spec.rb`](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/archive/language/super_spec.rb#L150))

Comment: I think this one is different, `args` is an array and `Array#<<` changes the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

It's the expected behaviour. Technically, `arg` is the same argument, it just points to another value.

This answer might explain it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872159/163640

Comment: I don't think that is relevant.

Comment: It explains how Ruby passes arguments to methods - how is that not relevant?