# Ruby temporary variable assignment and modification

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

I have a word like "hat", and I want to make a new word that is exactly the same, but with a different last letter.

```
word = "hat"
temp = word
temp[temp.length-1] = "d"

puts "temp is #{temp}"
puts "word is #{word}"

# Output:
# temp is had
# word is had
```

I would now expect  `temp = "had"` and `word = "hat"` but both of the words get changed to had!

I have a hunch that this might have to do with both variables pointing to the same location in memory?

Why is this happening, and how can I keep both values?

Comment: You can also use [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) with a regular expression: `'hat'.sub(/.$/,'d') #=> 'had'`. This does not alter `"hat"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening

You should definitely read this [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)

> how can I keep both values?

use `dup`. it copies the `object`

```
word = "hat"
temp = word.dup
temp[temp.length-1] = "d"

puts "temp is #{temp}"
puts "word is #{word}"

# Output:
# temp is had
# word is hat
```