# Why doesnt this ruby code work as expected?

Tags: ruby

I am working on learning some Hash operations in ruby. The code is about increasing each item's price by 10%. Why doesn't this code work?

```
restaurant_menu = { "Ramen" => 3, "Dal Makhani" => 4, "Coffee" => 2 }
restaurant_menu.each do |item, price|
  price = price + (price * 0.1)
end
```

while this one does:

```
restaurant_menu = { "Ramen" => 3, "Dal Makhani" => 4, "Coffee" => 2 }
restaurant_menu.each do |item, price|
  restaurant_menu[item] = price + (price * 0.1)
end
```

And any reasons as to why the latter is a better way to do it than the former as explained by @Mike Manfrin?

Comment: Yet another Ruby question arising from a misunderstanding of how object mutation works.

Comment: Can you explain or give some links so i can understand object mutation in ruby.I want to close this question as answered then.@Ajedi32

Comment: That's actually kind of why I mentioned it; I don't know of a canonical source explaining this concept.

Comment: @Ajedi32 . Any source would suffice canonical or non-canonical even chat messages would do.I want to understand why it happens.Seems kinda meta ruby now.

Comment: This is probably the closest thing I can find. The question isn't really the same, but the answers do go into a bit of detail about how mutation works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first one, you're setting the *local* variable of `price` to your new price, and then it gets discarded. `item` and `price` are scoped only to that one line they're used on.

In your second example, you are setting a variable, `restaurant_menu`, that exists outside the each block, so those changes will persist after the `each` block has finished running.

Comment: @MikeManfrin.That was fast but shouldn't what we write to price in its local scope be written to its Global  parent object ?

Comment: @Anony-mouse I get what you're trying to say, but there's no such thing as a "global parent object". Ruby just doesn't work that way. Do you have an example a language that does?

Comment: @Ajedi32.Thanking you for explaining me that.But what are advantages to this way than the first one?

Comment: There's no advantages -- they do different things. In the first you are iterating over each key/value pair (to do whatever you want), in the second one you're doing the same but also setting the price of each item in your outer-scoped hash.

Comment: Hi @Anony-mouse from the documentation at http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each your code "Calls block once for each key in [the hash], passing the key-value pair as parameters." Here, parameters means local variables essentially, and so they will 'vanish' once the block is completed unless you have stored them somewhere in a higher scope that can 'escape' the scope of the block.

Comment: @Anony-mouse You mean why is the language designed this way? Hmm, well I've never really seen an example of a language with a different behavior, so it's hard for me to say. My gut feeling is that, depending on the exact implementation, a language behaving the way you described would make it very easy to accidentally modify variables that you didn't intent to. I can't really say for sure though.

Comment: Also, `each` tends to be non-mutative; if you are changing values of a certain enumerable, `map` is the proper method. E.g., on arrays, `each` and `map` both iterate the same, but `map` returns a new version of the given array with the modified values (and `map!` will save to the original variable).

Comment: Thank you @DRSE ,@Mike Manfrin That was great i think i can close this question now.Should i wait ?

Comment: @MikeManfrin Sorry i wanted to upvote the answer but i think i donot have enough reputations.

Comment: @Anony-mouse Questions on StackOverflow don't get "closed" when they're answered.  Closing is reserved for questions that don't meet the quality standards of the site. Instead, you should accept an answer by clicking the check mark right below the voting buttons. (Or, if there is no answer which you believe answers your question, just leave the question open with no accepted answer.)

Comment: @Ajedi32 Done since i cant upvote anyways,I think i should do that.