# Update value inside the method

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, coming from C. 
I'd like to know how update a value in a method, like a pointer in C when I send the address as parameter.

```
def upd_value(str)
    str = "salut"
end

str = "bonjour"
upd_value(str)
puts str
```

I can use `replace` to change it, which worked.
It was a mistake though because I used a string as the example, and I want to update a Array. Any idea?

Comment: What do you want to do to the array? There are lots of ways to alter arrays.

Comment: Since you have several responses handling strings, you should open a new question asking about arrays. Future visitors are going to be confused, because now you're asking two different things.

Comment: This won't work for the exact same reason that it doesn't work in C, either: both languages are strictly pass-by-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "[Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)" on how Ruby handles arguments.

Generally speaking, you can pass an object to a method, modify the object attributes within that method and the modifications will still be there after the method returns.

What happens in your example though is shadowing of the parameter `str` by the local variable `str`. Since you make an assignment to the local variable and not to the passed argument, the modification is lost as soon as the method returns and its local scope is destroyed.

Your options are either return a value from the method and use it outside like this:

```
def my_method(str)
  str + 'salut' # a new instance of string is created and returned
end

str = 'hey, '
str = my_method(str)

puts str # outputs 'hey, salut'
```

or use a mutator method such as `#replace`

```
def my_method(str)
  str.replace('salut') # same string instance is reused
end

str = 'whatever'
my_method(str)

puts str # outputs 'salut'
```

You can handle easily handle passed arrays inside a method by changing values using index like so:

```
def my_method(array)
  array[15] = 10
end
```

Or add items via `<<`:

```
def my_method(array)
  array << 10
end
```

Or call its methods like this:

```
def my_method(array)
  array.delete(0)
end
```

All these modifications will be kept since the outer scope holds the reference to the same array instance you're operating on within the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-replace).

```
def change_str(str)
  str.replace 'goodbye'
end

str = 'hello'
change_str(str)
puts str
#=> goodbye
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, (almost) every variable is in fact a reference/pointer to an object, e.g.

```
a = [0, 1, 23]
b = a
a << 42
p b
```

will give `[0, 1, 23, 42`] because `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object.

So in fact, you are using pointers all the time.

If you want to do pointer arithmetic as in C, this is not possible with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The `str` within `upd_value` is in its own scope and won't affect the one outside it. You need to explicitly reassign it:

`str = upd_value(str)`

Comment: it's just an example of code, but my problem is with an Array, and it's dosn't work .. :/

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def upd_value(str = nil)
    str = str || "test"
end

str = "bonjour"
puts upd_value(str)
```