# instance variables don't seem to be populated in ruby method chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class I'm using build complex objects via method chaining. I'm new to ruby so I must be missing something obvious here. I expect a hash to be returned that looks like this: `{"must"=>[{:match=>{"status_type" : "good"}}, {:match=>{"product_age" : "old"}}]}`

But all I get is this: `{"must"=>[{:match=>{}}]}`

I invoke the following code for the above attempts:

```
builder = QueryBuilder.new
built = builder.must("status_type").equals("good").must("product_age").equals("old")
built.serialize_this
```

Here is my class. I'd appreciate any help as I'm pretty new to Ruby.

```
class QueryBuilder
    attr_accessor :query_hash, :context, :condition_hash

    def initialize
        @query_hash = {}
        @condition_hash = {}
    end

    def serialize_this
        return @query_hash
    end

    def must(search_field)
        @context = "must"
        @condition_hash[search_field] = "temp"
        return self
    end

    def should(search_field)
        @context = "should"
        @condition_hash[search_field] = "temp"
        return self
    end

    def equals(value_field)
        search_field = @condition_hash.keys[0].to_s
        @condition_hash[search_field] = value_field
        match_hash = {}
        match_hash[:match] = @condition_hash
        an_array =[]
        an_array << match_hash
        @query_hash[@context] = an_array
        @condition_hash.clear
    return self
    end
end
```

Thanks a ton in advance for any light you can shed on my code.

Comment: It is more idiomatic to not explicitly return something at the end of methods. For e.g., in the last line of the `equals` method, just write `self` instead of `return self`.

Comment: that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It shouldn't. I was saying that it's more idiomatic, not it will solve the problem.

Comment: That's true it is more idiomatic from what I've read. But return makes it easier to read. Some ruby industry experts are actually proponents to using return explicitly from what i have heard

Comment: True that certain people think it's easier to read. Just thought you should know since you mentioned you're new to Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

match_hash[:match] = @condition_hash

You don't put a copy of a Hash there, you put a reference to a hash. It's the very same hash that you clear later.

[Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)

Comment: great! that does fix the empty hash problem, but it missed out of status_type => good. It only shows the second hash which is: `{"must"=>[{:match=>{"product_age"=>"old"}}]}`

Comment: Of course, you instantiate a new array each time and put a value to it. The old array is lost.

Comment: got it. I see we have to do this: `(@query_hash[@context] ||= []) << match_hash
`