# Variable scope and modification

Tags: ruby

Why does calling the `mess_with_vars` method not modify the value of the variables shown within?

```
def mess_with_vars(one, two, three)
  one = "two"
  two = "three"
  three = "one"
end

one = "one"
two = "two"
three = "three"

mess_with_vars(one, two, three)

puts "one is: #{one}"
puts "two is: #{two}"
puts "three is: #{three}"
```

Comment: Read this article - http://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/

Comment: Thanks that was a helpful article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is pass-by-value ([Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)), so you can definitely modify the value of objects, and you will see its effects outside a method.

Consider these:

```
def mess_with_vars(one, two, three)
  one.gsub!('one','two')
  two.delete!("wo")
  three.replace "one"
end
```

All above modify the arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Because the scope of a local variable initialized in a method definition is the method definition.

Comment: I'd chalk it more up to pass-by-reference, no?

Comment: Okay, so if these were instance variables I'd expect the variables to be modified?

Comment: @JoeAinsworth Sorry for the previous comment. Yes. Since it is in the main environment, you can access the modified instance variables outside of the method definition.