# Hash variable is changed while being modified in function

Tags: ruby

I'm changing local variable `params` in `some_method`:

```
def some_method params
  params.object_id       # => 70163816155080 
  params[:name]  = 'bar'
  params.object_id       # => 70163816155080 Why is this not changing after I changed the value?
end

details  = {name: 'foo'}
details.object_id   # => 70163816155080
some_method details
details             # => {:name=>"bar"}
```

Why is it changing the original variable `details`? Does Ruby use pass by reference for hash?

Comment: what exactly is the question?  the method is changing the name key to `bar`

Comment: I'm changing local variable `params` on `some_method`. Why is is changing the original variable.Does Ruby pass by reference for hash?

Comment: .. i think your expecting `ruby` to act like `c` or some language where you need to pass a reference to a method to change the `concrete` object. `ruby` does not work that way.

Comment: @ptierno thank you !!  can you please describe in more details?

Comment: @BibekSharma not really, as I'm just learning languages with pointers and such myself (go/c). All I know is that ruby treats every object passed to a method as concrete, and in such modifies the ACTUAL object, not a copy of it. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)

Comment: @ptierno Thank you. It helps to make some sense.

Comment: @BibekSharma read some of the answers. I was wrong in about the my assumptions in a few situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some incorrect assumptions on your part

> I'm changing local variable params in some_method

No, you're not. Well, yes, you are changing *some state* of `params`, but the object is not replaced, it stays the same. Hence the persistence of its `object_id`. If you were to *replace* the object, then the object_id would change:

```
def some_method params
  params = { name: 'bar' } # this is a new object with a new object_id
                           # this assignment won't be visible to the outside
```

> Why is this not changing after I changed the value?

There are languages with immutable data structures. There you have to generate a new version of an object if you want to change some data in it. Ruby is not one of those languages. Its data structures are very mutable.

> Why is it changing the original variable details

Because these references refer to the same object in memory. See the many links about "pass-by-reference-by-value" posted in answers and comments here.

Comment: Perfect
You made my day !!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby pass everything by reference except Integer, Floats and Symbols just for convenience.

---

UPDATE:
It's called immediate values.

> immediate values are not pointers: Fixnum, Symbol, true, false, and
>   nil are stored directly in VALUE

You even can't define method for this kind of values:

```
x = :hello
def x.test; end
```

Will raise an error

---

MORE:

For example, Fixnum
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html

> Fixnum objects have immediate value. This means that when they are
>   assigned or passed as parameters, the actual object is passed, rather
>   than a reference to that object.

Comment: How did you come up with the idea that integers, strings and symbols are exceptions?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about Strings.
In ruby there are no thigs like passing by reference or not, actually.
But some types are immutable and they can't be changed inside of it, so new copy is created when you try to change it inside of function.

When you add to array new value or change existing, it will be changed outside of method.

Comment: @violarium, immutability has nothing to with whether something is passed by reference or by value. Something immutable can be passed either way in other languages.

Comment: @ptierno, this example doesn't prove anything. You can do the same with strings or any other type and the original `a` won't get changed. This is because the assignment operator (`=`) changes what something points to, it doesn't change the value in the passed reference.

Comment: @violarium Please see my update Why object_id is not getting changed after I changed the value

Comment: @violarium Can you please add some details. What are you trying to say exactly. "immediate values are not pointers: Fixnum, Symbol, true, false, and nil are stored directly in VALUE"?

Comment: @ndn, In ruby there are not passing by reference or by value like in other languages. Just some values are "immediate"

Comment: @violarium, immutability has nothing to do with this. By the same logic, you can say that each class that doesn't have anything to be mutated is also an exception.

Comment: @ndn, I called it in wrong way. Behaviour of passed variables depends on their trait "immediate". http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html

Comment: @BibekSharma, read this: ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html and just keep in mind that everything except this types are "passed by reference"