# Make hash keys map to the same value

Tags: ruby, hash, key, mapping

This is the hash I have:

```
color_hash = { sky: "blue", curtain: "blue", pavement: "black" }
```

Is there a way to change it to make two keys map to the same result, something like this:

```
color_hash = { sky or curtain: "blue", pavement: "black" }
```

I want to be able to use `color_hash[:sky]` and it would print `blue`, and I could use `color_hash[:curtain]` and it would print `blue`.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Do you mean `"sky or curtain": "blue"`?

Comment: no.  i want both keys mapping to the same result

Comment: Doesn't it already do what you want?

Comment: say the sky data, and the curtain data are related.  then if i change it once, i have to change it in two different places.  thats why i want two keys mapping to the same place, so i only have to change the value one time.

Comment: It already does what you want. It will return 'blue' for :sky and for :curtain

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do so with a default hash implementation in Ruby. See [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value). If this was possible, the setter method `[]=` on Hash would have to be implemented in such a way that allowed you to pass by reference.

You could implement something like this with some kludgy syntax and a subclass of Hash though... something like this (just a warning, this is still buggy and fairly untested, but gives you an idea as to what might be involved)

```
class FooHash < Hash
  attr_accessor :related

  def initialize(*args)
    @related = {}
    super
  end

  def []=(*args)
    raise ArgumentError.new("ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (#{args.length} for 2)") unless args.length > 1
    value = args.pop
    keys = args.dup

    args.each_index do |index|
      key = keys.delete_at(index)
      if related[key]
        related[key].each do |related_key|
          continue if keys.include?(related_key)
          super(related_key, value)
        end
      else 
        related[key] = []
      end
      related[key] += keys
      related[key].uniq!
      keys.insert(index, key)
    end

    args.each do |arg|
      super(arg, value)
    end
  end
end
```

It would allow you to do something like this:

```
1.9.3-p550 :036 > hsh = FooHash.new
 => {}
1.9.3-p550 :037 > hsh[:foo, :bar] = :baz
 => :baz
1.9.3-p550 :038 > hsh[:foo]
 => :baz
1.9.3-p550 :039 > hsh[:bar]
 => :baz
1.9.3-p550 :040 > hsh[:foo, :blah] = "baz2"
 => "baz2"
1.9.3-p550 :041 > hsh[:foo]
 => "baz2"
1.9.3-p550 :042 > hsh[:bar]
 => "baz2"
1.9.3-p550 :043 > hsh[:blah]
 => "baz2"
```

Long story short though, trying to imitate pointer manipulation in Ruby is kind of gross, don't do it.

Comment: Doing this would also break Ruby's default behavior of allowing an Array as a key which could have some pretty amazing side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Even I understand correctly what you want to do, consider using a different data structure.

```
color_hash = { sky: "blue", pothole: "black", curtain: "blue",
               pavement: "black", roadblock: "red" }
```

**You could use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):**

```
color_hash.group_by(&:last).tap { |h| h.each_key { |k| h[k].map!(&:first) } }
  #=> {"blue"=>[:sky, :curtain], "black"=>[:pothole, :pavement],
  #    "red"=>[:roadblock]}
```

**or [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update):**

```
color_hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h.update(v=>[k]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"blue"=>[:sky, :curtain], "black"=>[:pothole, :pavement],
  #    "red"=>[:roadblock]}
```

This uses the form of `Hash#update` (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }` is that block, where (the local variable) `_` is the key (rather than, say, `k`, to tell the reader that it's not used in the calculation), `o` ("old") is the value of the hash `h` for that key and `n` is the value of the hash being merged in for that key.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this.

```
  $someHashContainer = {:curtain => "Blue", :sky => "Blue"}

  def update_variables(value)
    $someHashContainer[:curtain] = value
    $someHashContainer[:sky] = $someHashContainer[:curtain]
  end

  puts $someHashContainer

  update_variables("Green")
  puts $someHashContainer

  $someHashContainer[:curtain] = "Red"
  puts $someHashContainer

  update_variables("Yellow")
  puts $someHashContainer


'''
OUTPUT:
{:curtain=>"Blue", :sky=>"Blue"}
{:curtain=>"Green", :sky=>"Green"}
{:curtain=>"Red", :sky=>"Green"}
{:curtain=>"Yellow", :sky=>"Yellow"}
'''
```