# Behavior of map and each for 2D arrays

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

While `each` does not change the values of a given row in a 2d array (unlike `map`):

```
test_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

test_array[0].each {|e| e = 1}
test_array # => [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

test_array[0].map! {|e| e = 1}
test_array # => [[1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

`each` changes the values of a given column (in a way different from `map`):

```
test_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

test_array.each {|row| row[0] = 2} 
test_array # => [[2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0]]

test_array.map! {|row| row[0] = 2}
test_array # => [2, 2, 2]
```

Can somebody explain what is happening?

Comment: `each` makes sense, but the question is why does `map!` replace each internal array with a `2` whereas `map` (without the `!` operator) returns `[[2,0],[2,0],[2,0]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because, in Ruby, parameters are 'passed by object reference'.

In the case below,

```
test_array.each {|row| row[0] = 2}
```

`row` refers to an array inside `test_array`, and modifying its contents will reflect in `test_array`. This mutates the sub-array present in `test_array`.

In the case below,

```
test_array[0].each {|e| e = 1}
```

`e` refers to an integer in `array[0]`, and making it point to a different integer will not impact the original value as we are not mutating the integer values present in `array[0]`.

More details here: [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)

Regarding your query on `map`, please note that you are using [`map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21), which will mutate the object on which the method is called, whereas `map` returns the value.

> `map! {|item| block } → ary`
>
> Invokes the given block once for each element of `self`, replacing the element with the value returned by the block.

Output of `map` is returned as is:

```
test_array.map {|row| row[0] = 2}
test_array # => [[2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0]]
```

`test_array` is replaced with output of `map`:

```
test_array.map! {|row| row[0] = 2}
test_array # => [2, 2, 2]
```