# Passing array to ruby function

Tags: ruby, sorting, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Okay, I got confused by how ruby passes it's arguments to a function. I've read in the documentation that ruby passes by **value**, but in my case it looks like it's passing by **referance**
Here's the problem:

```
def buble_sort(arr) 
unordered = true
while unordered
    unordered = false
    for i in (1..arr.size-1)
        if(arr[i-1] > arr[i])
            arr[i-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i-1] 
            unordered = true;
        end
    end
end
arr
end
```

Calling this method shouldn't modify the arr value, since ruby passes it by value. But in my case, it **does** modify the original array. Why?
Code:

```
p "#{arr} before sort" # => "[85, -4, 1, 2, 55, 23, 0] before sort"
p buble_sort(arr) # => [-4, 0, 1, 2, 23, 55, 85]
p "#{arr} after sort" # => "[-4, 0, 1, 2, 23, 55, 85] after sort"
```

Comment: A reference is a value. Unless you copy the array you're operating on the same array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)

Comment: You need to dup an object or to construct a new one, e. g. `def buble_sort(*arr)`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with pass-by-reference or pass-by-value. The difference between the two can only be observed when you re-bind the reference,  but you never do that, so the results are actually the same regardless of whether Ruby is pass-by-reference or pass-by-value. What you are seeing is simply mutable state. Ruby is not a purely functional language, it has mutable state and side-effects. This is an example of mutable state, and this is an example of why it should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand that, you have to make a distinction between a variable and what this variable stands for. Consider the following example :

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
# the variable items points to an array we just instantiated
items = [4, 5, 6]
# items now points to a new array
```

If ruby passed arguments by reference, doing so within a method with an argument it received would also make the variable exposed to the method by the caller point to a new location

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
def my_method array
    array = [4, 5, 6]
    return array
end
my_method(items) # --> [4, 5, 6]
items # --> [1, 2, 3]
# if ruby passed arguments by reference, items would now be [4, 5, 6]
```

Now ruby passes arguments by value, but the value you received is a reference to the same location in memory as the one the called passed you. In other words, you don't get a clone, a dup, but the same object.

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
def my_method array
    array << 4
    return array
end
my_method(items) # --> [1, 2, 3, 4]
items # --> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want your method to have no side-effect on its arguments you can clone them.

Comment: in Java, JavaScript and Ruby all variables are passed by value. Since every variable holds the reference of the object, called methods receives the copy of the reference. now there are two variables, one holding reference to the original object and second also holding the reference of the same object. Any object mutation operation will be seen through both the variables. Because same reference is copied and assigned to the method parameter it is called passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything in ruby is an object. In methods, objects are passed by reference.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

a is a variable whose value is the reference of an array.

```
def someMethod(b)
#...
end

someMethod(a)
```

here a's value is passed that is reference of the array, and it is received in the variable b. That means a and b both are having value as reference of the array.

```
def someMethod(b)
b = [4,5,6] 
end
```

here b is assigned a new value that is reference to the new array. a still has the reference of the original array as value.

Arrays are mutable, meaning we can change the content of array object.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[1]= 5
puts a
```

will print [1,5,3]

All primitive objects like numbers are immutable objects.

```
a =5
```

a stores the reference of an integer object which contains value 5.

```
a = a +1
```

now a stores the reference of an integer object which contains value 6. The object containing 6 is different than the object containing 5. The object containing 5 earlier, still contains 5 but its reference is not stored any where.