# Variable assignment inside of ruby methods

Tags: ruby

I have this pretty simple method:

```
def update_context(msg, session, sender)
    previous_context = session.context 
    session.update(context: intent_determination(msg, session.context, sender))
    session.update(context: brand_determination(msg, session.context))
    session.update(context: style_determination(msg, session.context))
    session.update(context: price_range_determination(msg, session.context))
    session.update(context: size_determination(msg, session.context))
       p previous_context
       p session.context
       p (previous_context == session.context)
    unless session.context.size == 0
      if previous_context == session.context
        session.context["intent"] = "lost"
        session.save
      end
    end
  end
```

My problem is certainly due to a stupid mistake I can't see but please bear with me on this one, I really can't see it.

As you can see, I "save" the session's context in a `previous_context` variable at the beginning of the method. Then, I'm running  a few updates on the context.
However, when I print `previous_context`, `session.context` and `previous_context == session.context`, I get the same result for the first two, and true for the last one.

How is this possible ? I assigned to `previous_context` the value of `session.context` before updating it. And then, `previous_context` has the same value as `session.context` after I've updated it.

I really can't see where I screwed up here, or there is definitely something I don't understand.

Comment: Though unrelated to your question, you could write `[:brand_determination, :style_determination, :price_range_determination, :size_determination].each { |m| session.update(context: send(m, msg, session.context)) }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the input, I appreciate it ! I'll update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previous_context = session.context` makes the previous_context variable point to the same object as session.context. If you want to change one without affecting the other, you'll need to create a copy of session.context to store in previous_context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I'm trying to do. I want a copy. How can I do this ? Should I use the clone method ?

Comment: depends on what type of object this context is. But `clone` or `dup` should work

Answer (score 0):

in Ruby, variables are just references to objects, so what you are doing there is merely creating a new reference to the same object. If you wish to save the previous state you will have to copy the entire object.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10974116/3569128) for a more graphic explanation.