# Understanding passing by value vs. reference in this Ruby example

Tags: ruby

After reading [Is ruby pass by reference or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value) I have learned a lot, but I am left with more questions than I had before reading it (which I suppose is good).

Consider the following example

```
def foo(bar) 
  bar = 'reference' 
end
baz = 'value' 
foo(baz)
puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"
```

**Output**
`Ruby is pass-by-value`

**Here is my attempt to dissect how this works:**

First, in the global scope `baz` has the value `value`.

Now `foo` takes a parameter, whatever you pass into it, is on a `local` level.

Therefore when we pass `baz` in, there is ANOTHER `baz` that is equal to `reference` but this is on the **local level**, as a result, when we puts this on a **global** level it prints `value`.

**Now consider another example**

```
def foo(bar)
  bar.replace 'reference' 
end
baz = 'value'
foo(baz)
puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"
```

**Output**

`Ruby is pass-by-reference`

If what I said above is true, does the `.replace` method here change the global `baz`? Am I interpreting this correctly? Please feel free to point out any mistakes in my attempts, I have no clue if im on the right track.

Thanks!

EDIT

**More Magic**

```
def my_foo(a_hash)
  a_hash["test"]="reference"
end;

hash = {"test"=>"value"}
my_foo(hash)
puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{hash["test"]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is pass-by-value, but the values are references to objects.

In your first experiment, `baz` is a reference to the string `"value"`. `bar` is initialized to a copy of `baz` (that is, a copy of the reference) when you call `foo`. You then overwrite `bar` with a reference to the string `"reference"`. Since `bar` is a copy, overwriting it doesn't change `baz`.

In your second experiment, again, `baz` is a reference to the string `"value"` and `bar` is initialized to a copy of `baz` when you call `foo`. This time you don't overwrite `bar`, but call a method on it. Although `bar` is a copy of `baz`, they refer to the same object (the string `"value"`). Calling the method changes the state of that object. You then call `to_s` on `baz` (indirectly, by substituting it into `"Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"`), and `to_s` returns the new state.

Your third experiment is a lot like the second. In the method, you change the state of the object referred to by the copy of the reference, then, outside the method, you read the new state back through the original reference.

Comment: You totally lost me on the second experiment part.. my brain doesent get it -__-

Comment: `bar` is not initialised to a copy of `baz` when you call `foo`. It refers to the same object in this first moment.

Comment: @bill I reworded. If that's not clearer, let me know what part isn't clear.

Comment: @FranMartinez it is initialized to a copy of the _reference_.

Comment: OoOoOoOoOoOoOo Makes sense.. Is the first example the same logic for my newly edited example?

Comment: Actually it's the second and third examples that are almost the same. I added that to my answer.

Comment: But I thought the third example is the same as the first, we use `=` since `a_hash` is a copy it doesent change the original `hash`

Comment: In the third example you copy `hash` (which a reference to an object) to `a_hash` (which is a copy, but refers to the same object). You then call a method (`[]=`) on that object which changes its state. That's much like example 2, where you called `replace` on the string.

Comment: I never knew calling `[]` is calling a method... so basically almost in all cases we will get `reference`?. The only time we really get value is when directly setting the method variable to something else (`bar = reference`)

Comment: That is, in the first example, the method gets a copy of the reference but you don't do anything to it before you overwrite it, so the object that `baz` points to is unchanged.

Comment: Hi, I asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274077/what-is-the-usage-of-self-in-this-ruby-example. If you have time you can check it out

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting thing.

Play with the `object_id`s, you will see what ruby is doing bellow the scenes:

```
def foo(bar)
  puts bar.object_id
  bar = 'reference'
  puts bar.object_id
end

baz = 'value'
puts baz.object_id
foo(baz)
```

**Output**

```
> baz = 'value'
=> "value"

> puts baz.object_id
70241392845040

> foo(baz)
70241392845040
70241392866940
```

After the local assign `bar = 'reference'`, the local variable `bar` will reference another object, so it won't change the original one.

It seems that in some cases it will make a `dup` of your object.

Comment: it seems .`replace` doesent*  change the `object_id`, why is that? Also I added another  example wit hashes if you would like to take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help to understand it:

```
x = 'ab'
x.object_id
=> 70287848748000 # a place in memory

x = 'cd'
x.object_id
=> 70287848695760 # other place in memory (other object)

x.replace('xy')
x.object_id
=> 70287848695760 # the same place in memory (the same object)
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually has nothing to do with passing parameters to methods. I extracted important parts from your examples:

```
baz = 'value'
bar = baz
bar = 'reference'
puts baz
bar = baz
bar.replace 'reference'
puts baz
```

You may think of variables as pointers. When you use `=`, you make a variable point to something different, and the original value remains unchanged, and can be accessed through other variables that point at it. But when you use `replace`, you change the content of the string the variable points at.

Comment: Ok gonna take a look at this and other answers, I added another magic example by the way

Answer (score 0):

In first case you use `bar = 'reference'` which creates new object. In second one `.replace` changes the object you apply it to. You can ensure this by `.object_id` method. For example:

```
def foo_eql(bar)
  bar = 'reference'
  puts bar.object_id
  bar
end

def foo_replace(bar)
  bar.replace 'reference'
  puts bar.object_id
  bar
end

baz = 'value'
puts baz.object_id #Here you will get original baz object_id
res1 = foo_eql(baz) #Here you will get printed new object_id
res2 = foo_replace(baz) #Here you will get printed original baz object_id
puts "foo_eql: Ruby is pass-by-#{res1}"
=> foo_eql: Ruby is pass-by-reference
puts "foo_replace: Ruby is pass-by-#{res2}"
=> foo_replace: Ruby is pass-by-reference
```

So there is no magic at all. In your example with hashes you do not create new Hash object but modify existing one. But you can create new one with method like this:

```
def my_foo(a_hash)
  a_hash = a_hash.merge({"test" => "reference"})
end
my_foo(hash)
puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{hash["test"]}"
```

Basically  you pass the reference to an object in "**value**" way. For better understanding check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872159/4470392) and comments to it.