# why return change variables while inside a class

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I cannot understand this ruby behavior, the code explains better what I mean:

```
class DoNotUnderstand
    def initialize
        @tiny_array = [3,4]
        test
    end

    def messing(ary)
        return [ary[0]+=700, ary[1]+=999]
    end

    def test
        puts @tiny_array.join(",")  # before => 3,4
        messing(@tiny_array)
        puts @tiny_array.join(",")  # after  => 703,1003
    end
end

question = DoNotUnderstand.new
```

`@tiny_array` was `[3,4]` and became `[703,1003]`
if I don't use a class, that happens:

```
@tiny = [1,2]
def messing(ary)
    return [ary[0]+693,ary[1]+999]
end

puts @tiny.join(",")                        # before  => 1,2
messing(@tiny)
puts @tiny.join(",")                        # after   => 1,2
```

the array simply remains `[1,2]`
why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class is a red herring, and completely irrelevant to the issue.

In the first case, where the array was modified, you defined `messing` as:

```
def messing(ary)
  return [ary[0]+=700, ary[1]+=999]
end
```

Whereas in the second case, where the array was *not* modified, you defined `messing` as:

```
def messing(ary)
  return [ary[0]+693,ary[1]+999]
end
```

In one case you used `+=`, and in the other, you used merely `+`.

`ary[0] += 700` is exactly equivalent to `ary[0] = ary[0] + 700`. In other words you are changing the value stored in the 0th index of `ary`.

In the second case you merely add to the values stored in the array and return the result, but in the first case you not only return the result, you also store it back in the array.

For an explanation of why modifying `ary` modifies `@tiny_array`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value/10974116#10974116) to the question [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value/10974116).

Answer (score 2):

You're second code example (the one from outside the class) is missing the two characters in the first that make it work the way it does. In the first example, the `+=` operator is used, modifying the array in place:

```
return [ary[0]+=700, ary[1]+=999]
```

In your second example, the `+` operator is used, leaving the array as is:

```
return [ary[0]+693,ary[1]+999]
```

If you change it use the `+=` operator, it works the same way as the first code snippet.