# Instance variable changes without explicitly telling it to

Tags: ruby

This is a very weird one.

So I have a class `LibSystem`

```
class LibSystem
  attr_accessor :borrower
  attr_reader :books
  def initialize(book_inventory = [])
    @borrower = []
    @books = book_inventory
    @borrowed = []
  end
#...
end
```

From another file I do `require_relative` and the file which contains it. Then I do this...

```
#...
sys = LibSystem.new(books)
puts sys.books.length
books << Book.new("Adventure Of My New Cat", "3-598-21515-0", "3", "funny publications", "2001", [auth3], 1)
puts sys.books.length
```

What I expect is for the first length to be 9 (size of the array I passed to the constructor) and the second to be the same. Instead I get 9 and 10 accordingly. This seems like the instance variable inside my `sys` object is updating along with the array that was passed into it. This seems completely wrong to me. Am I doing anything wrong here, or is this the standard behavior? Thank you.

The title is probably inaccurate, if you have anything better, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays and hashes in Ruby are by default *not copied*.  Inside `LibSystem` you assign the passed `book_inventory` to the `@books` instance variable; Your new `LibSystem` instance just holds on the *address* of the existing array without copying the contents.  When you used `<<` to append to the array, you modified the *same array*.

It is sometimes considered a good practice to copy the arrays or dictionaries used in an initializer to avoid exactly this kind of interference, although your use case may vary.

Comment: Would making a duplicate of the array and passing that, work, and above all, be a good practice? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest instead of copying before you call, make your initializer copy the array before assigning to the instance variable - that way, regardless of how well written the code that calls your LibSystem class is, your class has an expectation that nobody will interfere with it's state.

Comment: And I would consider that to be perfectly reasonable practice.  Not always the most efficient, but I will choose correctness and reliability over efficiency in nearly every application.

Comment: Check Abe Voelker's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)