# Ruby - Pushing Hash to Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

While iterating, I am saving some data to a hash each time. Within the same loop, I push the hash to an array.

The below code does not work, the last hash object overwrites all the other ones in the array.

```
playlists = []
aPlaylist = {}

while (count < 3)
    #some code... produces the hash "aPlaylist"
    playlist << aPlaylist
end
```

The code below does work. Why, and what is the difference?

```
playlists = []

while (count < 3)
    aPlaylist = {}
    #some code... produces the hash "aPlaylist"
    playlist << aPlaylist
end
```

Here are the correct and wrong outputs (converted to csv):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISqj.jpg.

Comment: _"the last hash object overwrites all the other ones in the array"_ – could you show the erroneous result?

Comment: This depends entirely on the "some code" you left out.

Comment: I updated the question with images.

@JörgWMittag I don't think so, the other answers explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, in the first case, the object is same that is on 0, 1, and 2nd index.

```
playlist = []
aPlaylist = {}
count = 0

while (count < 3)
    #some code... produces the hash "aPlaylist"
    playlist << aPlaylist
    puts aPlaylist.object_id
    count += 1
end
#=> 2048
#=> 2048
#=> 2048
```

While in second case it changes:

```
playlist = []

count = 0

while (count < 3)
    aPlaylist = {}
    #some code... produces the hash "aPlaylist"
    playlist << aPlaylist
    puts aPlaylist.object_id
    count += 1
end
#=> 2048
#=> 2038
#=> 2028
```

Which is why from second case when you make changes to hash, it does not get reflected in all places in array.

Read [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10974116/645886) for more detail.

Comment: Oh I see now. 

So basically as I update aPlaylist in each iteration, it is sort of a pass-by-reference to the array and they change too.

This is a bit unintuitive for me, coming from C++ background.

Comment: @emre be careful that you don't end up writing C++ in Ruby.

Comment: @david care to elaborate on that? I'm a bachelor doing his first internship so not really experienced.

Comment: @emre I added an answer with an idiomatic Ruby methodology, so please see that. `while` loops and incrementing counters are pretty rare in Ruby, where map/reduce and other such methodologies are more common. I'd recommend any talk by Sandy Metz (various YouTube ones available) and her book http://www.poodr.com for tips. The more OO you are, the better Ruby will treat you :)

Answer (score 0):

`aPlaylist = {}` creates a hash and `aPlaylist` variable holds a pointer to the hash object.

In your first example you edit only this one hash object.

```
aPlaylist = {}
count = 0
while (count < 3)
  puts aPlaylist.object_id
  count += 1
end
#=> 70179174789100
#=> 70179174789100
#=> 70179174789100
```

In your second example you create a new hash object within each iteration. That's way this code works.

```
count = 0
while (count < 3)
  aPlaylist = {}
  puts aPlaylist.object_id
  count += 1
end
#=> 70179182889040
#=> 70179182888980
#=> 70179182888920
```

Have a look to the printed object-ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think an idiomatic Ruby approach would be something like ...

```
playlist = 0.upto(2).map{|count| something_that_returns_a_hash }
```

... or ...

```
playlist = (0..2).map{|count| something_that_returns_a_hash }
```

Hence:

```
0.upto(2).map{|count| {count => count} }

[{0=>0}, {1=>1}, {2=>2}]
```