# What is a good way to access instances?

Tags: ruby

How do I write my class to access array for different objects?

```
class ListArray
  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize arr
    @arr = arr
  end
end

a = ListArray.new([0, 1, 2, 3])
b = ListArray.new(a.arr)
a.arr[2] = 999
b.arr[2] = 4
a.arr[2] #=> 4  ?
b.arr[2] #=> 4
```

When I changed value of `b.arr[2]` to 4, `a.arr[2]` value (which should be 999) takes the value 4.

I don't know what I did wrong.

[edit]

My full code looks more like this:

```
class OtherClass
   def list
end

class ListArray
   attr_accessor :arr
   def initialize arr
      @arr = arr
   end
   def putItem ...
   def getItem ...
   def cutList &bloc ...
end

a = ListArray.new obj1_other_class.list
  # obj2_other_class.list =>  [[1, 2], [3, 4], ... ]
  # [3, 4] is an item
b = ListArray.new obj2_other_class.list
a.putItem [5, 6]
c = ListArray.new a.arr
c.arr += b.arr
c.arr[1][0] = 7
      ...
```

How can I avoid object's same id problems?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What did you do wrong? If you don't know, how should we know?

Comment: Ruby follow call by reference for array most of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ListArray
  attr_accessor :arr
  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end
  def arr_object_id
    @arr.object_id
  end
end
```

Create an instance of `ListArray`, creating an instance variable `@arr` equal to `[0, 1, 2, 3]`:

```
a = ListArray.new [0, 1, 2, 3] 
  #=> #<ListArray:0x0000574d960e19e8 @arr=[0, 1, 2, 3]>
```

Let's check the value of `@arr` and retrieve its object id:

```
a.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
a.arr_object_id
  #=> 47995370802440
```

Now create another instance of `ListArray`, creating its  instance variable `@arr` and setting it equal to the value of `a.arr`:

```
b = ListArray.new(a.arr)
  #=> #<ListArray:0x0000574d9611bdf0 @arr=[0, 1, 2, 3]> 
b.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
b.arr_object_id
  #=> 47995370802440
```

The interesting thing here is that `a.arr_object_id == b.arr_object_id`. That's not surprising, however, because we initialized `b`'s instance variable to `a`'s instance variable, so *they are the same object*!

Next, change the value of `a`'s instance variable to `[0, 1, 999, 3]`:

```
a.arr[2] = 999
a.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 999, 3] 
a.arr_object_id
  #=> 47995370802420
```

Check if the value of `b`'s instance variable has changed:

```
b.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 999, 3] 
b.arr_object_id
  #=> 47995370802440
```

It has, because `a`'s and `b`'s instance variables `@arr` hold the same object.

To make `b`'s instance variable hold an array whose instance variables are the same as `a`'s, but make the two arrays different objects, create `b` with its instance variable `@arr` equal to a *copy* of the value of `a`'s instance variable:

```
a = ListArray.new [0, 1, 2, 3]
  #=> #<ListArray:0x0000574d9610d818 @arr=[0, 1, 2, 3]> 
a.arr_object_id 
  #=> ...320 
b = ListArray.new(a.arr.dup)
  #=> #<ListArray:0x0000574d961143c0 @arr=[0, 1, 2, 3]> 
b.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
b.arr_object_id
  #=> ...100 (different than a.arr_object_id)
a.arr[2] = 19
a.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 19, 3] 
b.arr
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

But, wait, we're not finished. Here's a second example that illustrates why you cannot always merely apply `dup`.

```
a = ListArray.new [0, [1, 2], 3]
  #=> #<ListArray:0x0000574d9614b370 @arr=[0, [1, 2], 3]> 
a.arr_object_id 
  #=> ...700 
a.arr[1].object_id
  #=> ...720 
a.arr[1][1].object_id
  #=> 5 
2.object_id
  #=> 5 

b = ListArray.new(a.arr.dup)
  #=> #<ListArray:0x0000574d96119258 @arr=[0, [1, 2], 3]> 
b.arr
  #=> [0, [1, 2], 3] 
b.arr_object_id
  #=> ...160  (different than a.arr_object_id)
b.arr[1].object_id
  #=> ...720 (same as a.arr[1].object_id) 
b.arr[1][1].object_id
  #=> 5
```

Now change the value of `a.arr[1][1]`:

```
a.arr[1][1] = 9
a.arr
  #=> [0, [1, 9], 3] (as expected) 
a.arr[1].object_id
  #=> ...720 (no change) 
b.arr
  #=> [0, [1, 9], 3]
b.arr[1].object_id 
  #=> ...720 (no change)
```

You see this changes `b[1][1]` as well. That's because the *contents* of the object that is the value of both `a.arr[1]` and `b.arr[1]` has been altered. Now try this.

```
a.arr[1] = [8, 0]
a.arr
  #=> [0, [8, 0], 3] (as expected) 
a.arr[1].object_id
  #=> ...880 (a new object!) 
b.arr
  #=> [0, [1, 9], 3] (unchanged!) 
b.arr[1].object_id 
  #=> ...720 (unchanged)
```

For this example we would need to write:

```
a = ListArray.new [0, [1, 2], 3]
b = ListArray.new(a.arr.dup.map { |e| e.dup })

a.arr[1][1] = 9
a.arr
  #=> [0, [1, 9], 3] 
b.arr
  #=> [0, [1, 2], 3] (no change!)
```

`a.arr.dup.map { |e| e.dup }` is referred to as a *deeper copy* of `a.arr` than is `a.arr.dup`. If there were yet deeper nested arrays (`[1, [2, [3, 4]], 5]`) we would have to `dup` to lower levels of `a.arr`. For a Ruby newbie it's not important to fully understand how *deep copies* are constructed, merely that they are needed to achieve independence for duped copies of objects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very complete answer! I really like to understand! I didn't think I had to worry about id's object before a long time...

Comment: You’ve got a small typo just after your 4th code block — just after “The interesting thing here”, you’re missing `_id` on `b.arr_object`. I tried to submit an edit, but it had to be at least 6 characters different, and this was only 3...

Comment: No problem, @CarySwoveland! Solid explanation, btw.

Comment: Is it possible to implement 'a.arr.dup.map { |e| e.dup }' in initialize's method to avoid problems every time you call ListArray?

Comment: µ, one could do that but it would be problematic if a nested array were ever passed to the method. If the array should always contain only literals--say integers--you could check that  (in `initialize`) before `@arr = arr.dup` (e.g., `raise ArgumentError, "not all elements of #{arr} are integers" unless arr.all? { |n| n.is_a?  Integer }`) .

Answer (score 3):

By

```
b = ListArray.new a.arr
```

You actually transfer the reference of `a.arr` to b, not it's value.

You can do it like this:

```
b = ListArray.new a.arr.dup
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value), which is about the argument passing of reference or value.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to learn what i can about .dup () and maybe .clone ()

Comment: Sure thing. Glad to hear about that :)