# Why does ruby mutate my array when I do not ask it to?

Tags: ruby, clone

There are two methods below; both are the same except one `clone`s the input whereas the other does not.

**Method 1**

```rb
arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3]

def remove_smallest(array)
  new = array
  new.reject! {|i| i <= new.min}
  new
end

remove_smallest(arr)
#=> [2,3,2,3]
arr
#=> [2,3,2,3]
```

**Method 2**

```rb
arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3]

def remove_smallest(array)
  new = array.clone
  new.reject! {|i| i <= new.min}
  new
end

remove_smallest(arr)
#=> [2,3,2,3]
arr
#=> [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Without the `clone`, the method will mutate the original input even if I perform all operations on a copy of the original array.

Why is an explicit `clone` method needed to avoid this mutation?

Comment: Use `reject` instead. The `!` (bang) refers to destructive methods.

Comment: `new = array` does not make a copy of the array. It makes a copy of the _reference_ to the array. There is still only one array. I suggest you run both snippets through [this visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/ruby.html), which should show you what is happening.

Comment: @Sabastian has answered your question, but here are a couple more points. You don't need a variable `new` and you don't need `new` by itself as the last line. All you need for the body of the method is this: `array.reject {|i| i <= array.min}`. As that's the last statement of method it's return value becomes the return value of the method. As `array.min` is within the block it is execute `array.size` times, which is inefficient.  Also, `<=` is the same as `==` and the former is confusing. Instead, write `n = array.min` followed by `array.reject {|i| i == n }`

Comment: maybe have a look here for  more insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sebastian hasn't answered the question. Amadan has.

Comment: @sawa, yes. By way of explanation, I started writing my comment before Amadan posted his comment and was focused on the somewhat extraneous points I made.

Comment: One could write `def remove_smallest(array); array - [array.min]; end`. Like [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-reject), [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) is order-preserving.

Answer (score 10):

> [...] will mutate the original input even if I perform all operations on a copy of the original array.

You don't perform the operations on a copy. When doing

```
new = array
```

it doesn't result in a copy operation. Instead, the assignment makes `new` simply refer to the same object `array` is referring to. It therefore doesn't matter if you invoke `new.reject!` or `array.reject!` because `reject!` is sent to the same receiver.

> Why is an explicit `.clone` method needed to avoid this mutation?

Because [`clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Object.html#method-i-clone) performs the copy operation you've assumed for `=`. From the docs:

> Produces a shallow copy of *obj* [...]

Another way to avoid this mutation is to use a non-mutating method instead:

```
def remove_smallest(array)
  array.reject {|i| i <= array.min }
end
```

or – to avoid re-calculating the minimum on each step:

```
def remove_smallest(array)
  min = array.min
  array.reject {|i| i <= min }
end
```

You can also use `==` instead of `<=` because `min` is already the smallest possible value.

Alternatively, there's [`Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-2D):

```
def remove_smallest(array)
  array - [array.min]
end
```

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive answer -- that thanks goes to everyone who commented above too!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've made this a community wiki, feel free to edit :-)