# Efficient way to pass variable in method and store result in same param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, parameters

Is there an efficient or a shorter way to achieve the same result as below?

```
params[:random] = split_array(params[:random])
```

I want to pass a variable as parameter to a rails method and store the result in the same variable and use it further?

For example, I was thinking something similar to

```
variable = variable + 1
```

can be efficiently written as

```
variable++
```

Comment: Actually `variable++` is not possible in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

What you were saying could be achieved if you passed `params[:random]` by reference, but that is not achievable in ruby since ruby is strictly [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value).

The line `params[:random] = split_array(params[:random])` is perfectly fine (not very verbose).

Comment: Note: even if you found a way of passing by reference in ruby, you should not. If that line really will be a problem to your code readability (e.g. if you are using it in many lines), maybe there is an object or something else missing in your code architecture; but that is just speculation on my side