# What is the difference between these two memory assignments?

Tags: arrays, ruby, assign

I tried to solve a kata today that took me through a loop through one portion of the exercise. The problem I experienced can be simplified to the following nuance:

```
node = [1]
root_node = node

node << 2

p node #[1,2]
p root_node #[1,2]

node = 1
root_node = node

new_node = 3
node = new_node


p node #3
p root_node #1
```

Why is it that `node` and `root_node` both change when I modify the array assigned to one variable but assigning values to a variable doesn't modify the other?

I would have expected `node = [1,2]` and `root_node = [1]`.

Could someone shed light onto this or direct me towards documentation regarding this. I don't think I ever noticed that that was the case. Thank you.

Comment: `<<` changes the object the variable is referring to whereas `=` changes the variable itself. If two variables refer to the same object (like in the first example) and you change that object, the change is reflected by both variables.

Comment: you probably wanted to do `root_node = node.dup` in your second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an array, the variable holds a value of a reference to this array. When you assign this to another variable, the reference is copied. Then when you call `<<` mutating the array, it's visible under both variables, because there is only one array.

When you assign an integer, the a value of this integer is stored in the variable. When you reassign it, another value is stored in this variable. There is no difference if you reassign it using a constant `a = 1` or another variable `a = b`.

An important thing to note is that assignment works this way also for arrays - the value of the reference is reassigned. If you assign another array, the original one is not changed.

```
node = [1]
root_node = node
new_node = [3]
node = new_node
p node
#[3]
p root_node
#[1]
```

See also:

- https://learn.co/lessons/pass-by-reference
- [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)
- https://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/

Comment: Thx, fixed that