# How to modify a number passed into a method as an argument

Tags: ruby

#### Background

I have a method which in which I want to modify a number which will be passed into the method, but not returned.

#### Example

```rb
def increase_number_by_one_and_do_some_other_stuff(number)
    number = number + 1
    some_other_stuff = "Other stuff I want to happen in this function"
    some_other_stuff
end

number = 1

increase_number_by_one_and_do_some_other_stuff(number)

puts number
# => 1
## Expecting 2
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Ruby, or is it always Pass by Value? I have [tried to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value) exactly how object references/values are treated in Ruby, but for my level of experience it's quite confusing still.

#### More context

The situation I'm trying to use it is something like this. Tried to keep it simple but still give enough information.

```rb
total = 1000
unaccounted_for = 100
accounted_for = total - unaccounted_for

distribute_unaccounted(unaccounted_for, accounted_for)

puts unaccounted_for
# => 55
puts accounted_for
# => 945

def distributed_unaccounted(unaccounted_for, accounted_for)
   # lots of code
   category_a_reaccounted = 25 # calculated within this method
   category_b_reaccounted = 20 # calculated within this method
   total_reaccounted = category_a_reaccounted + category_b_reaccounted
   unaccounted_for -= total_reaccounted
   accounted_for += total_reaccounted
end
```

Comment: Ruby is always pass-by-value. The `number` variable within the method exists in a separate variable scope. Assigning a new object to the variable via `number = number + 1` is limited to the method. Variables outside the method aren't affected.

Comment: With local variables it's impossible, you can use instance variable, for example, `@number` and then in method `@number = @number+1`(`@number += 1`) or you can return `number` in the end of method and then `number = increase_number_by_one_and_do_some_other_stuff(number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a method which in which I want to modify a number ...

Numbers are immutable, you cannot change them. `1` will always be `1`.

I think what you actually want is to assign a new value to the `number` variable within your method and the `number` variable outside your method.

But that's not possible in Ruby. The variables inside your methods have their own variable scope and changes don't propagate outside. So assigning a new object to a variable inside your method won't affect "outside" variables.

> Is there any way to achieve this in Ruby ...

What I see are several values and methods that work on those values. Why not move them into a class, as instance variables and instance methods?

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :total, :unaccounted_for

  def initialize(total, unaccounted_for)
    @total = total
    @unaccounted_for = unaccounted_for
  end

  def accounted_for
    total - unaccounted_for
  end

  def category_a_reaccounted
    25 # actually calculated
  end

  def category_b_reaccounted
    20 # actually calculated
  end

  def distributed_unaccounted
    total_reaccounted = category_a_reaccounted + category_b_reaccounted
    @unaccounted_for -= total_reaccounted
  end
end
```

Usage, based on your example:

```
foo = Foo.new(1000, 100)

foo.unaccounted_for #=> 100
foo.accounted_for   #=> 900

foo.distributed_unaccounted

foo.unaccounted_for #=> 55
foo.accounted_for   #=> 945
```

Comment: "Why not move both into a class, as instance variable and instance method?"

Well, it works...but it seems a huge hassle just to increment a number.

Comment: @ChrisA I assumed that number and method are closely related, that's why I suggested to move them into their own class. Maybe you could give a bit more context / meaning. What is that number and what is the method supposed to do? Why is the number incremented within the method?

Comment: @ChrisA thanks for the additional information. It seems as if you do much more than just incrementing a number. I would definitely recommend to encapsulate the related data and calculations in a class, see my updated example.