# Unexpected returned value from Array#map

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm getting an unexpected return value with this code:

```rb
str = ''; 'abc'.chars.map {|c| str<<c}
```

Expected output:

```rb
["a", "ab", "abc"]
```

Actual output:

```rb
["abc", "abc", "abc"]
```

Adding a `puts(str)` for debugging:

```rb
str = ''; 'abc'.chars.map {|c| puts(str); str<<c}

a
ab
=> ["abc", "abc", "abc"]
```

Why is the above code not returning the expected output?
Thanks.

Comment: You can avoid this confusion by using the `# frozen_string_literal: true` directive. It will prevent you from using destructive methods like `String#<<`. There is a performance penalty in some scenarios, but the tradeoff is worth it for most teams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3C-3C):

> **string << object → string**.
> Concatenates `object` to `self` and returns `self`

So `str << c` in the block alters `str` and then the block itself evaluates to `str`.

You could say this to get the results you're after:

```
str = ''
'abc'.chars.map { |c| (str << c).dup }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Now i know a bit more about ruby blocks. So Object#oid was the same, so the block returned `str` multiple times. I needed `dup` to create a different object on each iteration.

Comment: @builder-7000 you don't have to use `dup` necessarily, you could also create new objects by re-assigning `str`, e.g. `'abc'.chars.map { |c| str = "#{str}#{c}" }`

Answer (score 2):

It's because each element in your map is returning a *reference* to `str`'s value, not the actual value of `str`. So your map is returning 3 references to the value of `str` and not the value of `str` at the time of iteration; because each reference to `str` points to one place in memory at the end that has `'abc'`, that's why you see the final value of `str` 3 times.

Comment: You might find some of the answers to this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value