# Can Ruby check 'nil' if I pass nothing into a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this weird behavior of my helper and suspect is has something to do with [Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value), can I ask for your help to explain the behavior?

views/xxx.html

```
helperA(@object.attribute_A)
```

helperA.rb

```
def helperA(object)
    if object == nil
       return 
    end 
    # do something if not nil
```

However when nothing is passed into the helper(object does not have attribute_A), the 'if object == nil' doesn't catch the situation and continue running the code, which usually will cause error like "undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass" that's because of the later operation in helper.

My question is why is this happening?

Comment: You can also use `object.nil?` or since this is tagged Rails, you can also use `object.blank?` to catch all falsy values such as `nil, 0, '', ' '`

Also are you sure that `length` comes from `object` and not from another attribute?

Comment: `object == nil` isn't idomatically correct Ruby. Use `object.nil?` or just `if object` since everything except nil and false is truthy.

Comment: If `object` does not have `attribute_A` then wouldn't `@object.attribute_A` raise a `NoMethodError` exception? So what does `@object.attribute_A` actually do when `@object` does not have `attribute_A`?

Comment: agree with @muistooshort , looks like object.attribute_A is not raising an exception but returning something, and that something isn not nil.  Once you fix that (make it return nil or raise exception) your example would work.

Comment: thank you guys, I added a default value to the helper (helperA(object="") and catch ("") in the first line solved the issue. using object.blank? will work too.  
  
agree with @muistooshort and JoelBlum that I need to look into the object to really understand what'd happen while .attribute_A is called when .attribute_A is nil

Comment: _"when nothing is passed into the helper"_ – then Ruby won't call the method but instead raise an `ArgumentError` because the `object` argument is mandatory. In other words: if `helper` gets called, something _is_ being passed. You might want to inspect `object` within your helper to understand what it is. `p object` and / or `puts object.class` should get you started.

Comment: Show your code where you would "pass nothing" to the function. You have to supply a parameter when calling this function (otherwise you get an exception), and there is no piece of data in the Ruby world which would be "nothing". Therefore, I don't understand what you are doing in your program.

Comment: BTW, it is important to use the right terminology with such tricky questions: Ruby does not have "attributes" (even though the methods named `attr_reader` and so on may mislead in believing that it has. If you do a `@object.attribute_A`, you are invoking a method named `attribute_A` on @object. If this method does not exist, you get an exception. If this method exists, it must return some value (it is not possible in Ruby to write _void_ methods which don't return a value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
# set object to default as nil
def helperA(object = nil)
  return nil if object.nil? ## use object.blank? if you want empty strings, empty hashes and empty arrays to be caught in addition to nil

  # do something if not nil 
end
```

you can also do something with what you are passing into the input

```rb
helperA(@object&.attribute_A) # tells the function to treat the input as nil if the @object doesn't exist
```